# Getting " package org.apache.log4j does not exist " error

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to run my java code but I am getting this series of errors :

```
Start.java:11: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                       ^
Start.java:12: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import static org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger;
                              ^
Start.java:12: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger;
^
Start.java:13: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import static org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure;
                              ^
Start.java:13: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure;
^
```

This is how my `pom.xml` file looks :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help, and do tell me if you want any more information.
Thanks.

Comment: For me, this looks a problem with maven or the lib itself. Try reimporting the maven projects in the IDE or deleting the lib from the .m2 folder and reimporting the maven project.

Comment: a noob question, but do i need to download log4j or is it just a library which i can import?

Comment: This log4j should be downloaded by Maven defined in your pom.xml. Are you using an IDE? Eclipse/Intellij? in the pom.xml, you would have the option maven->reimport or something.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding log4j home to the classpath as the JVM needs the path to the log4j classes

Windows:

```
set classpath=%classpath%;%LOG4J_HOME%
```

Linux/Ubuntu:

```
export classpath=$classpath:$LOG4J_HOME
```

then run your app after adding other paths to classpath

```
set classpath=%classpath%;c:\users\nb12345\...
```

LOG4J_HOME is not known to Java. It is just used by log4j in case of auto config/default config.

Comment: Your maven dependency should take care of downloading the jars. You need not do it explicitly. Try rebuilding and running your maven project. Make sure you get log4j downloaded after successful run.

Comment: @Nilanjan it is failing in compilation time. i don't see how setting an environment variable would help. I don't have it and it works for me. It is a problem with maven not downloading the dependency for some reason.

Comment: I think i am not using a maven dependency ( as in an IDE or something ) , I am running this directly on command prompt, bear me i am a noob.

Comment: Do you have Maven installed?

Comment: Take a look here: https://maven.apache.org/install.html and https://metamug.com/article/build-run-java-maven-project-command-line.html

Comment: how to check if maven is installed? @Thilo i just used the normal javac program.java command

Comment: If you want to use javac directly, you indeed have to download log4j (and maybe other things) and set up your CLASSPATH variable. I strongly recommend learning how to use Maven instead.

Comment: No, I do not have maven. So than I just need to install maven right? and than use mvn compile or something?

Comment: yes, mvn compile and then mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=your.package.Main